# Lombok (@__) error on Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, lombok

I've got the problem that neither eclipse nor the newest Spring Tool Suite 
seems to be able to handle @__ (lombok).

Using the following

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Autowired))
```

lets eclipse underlay the @__ with an error indicator and the text:

> The value for annotation attribute RequiredArgsConstructor.onConstructor must be some @lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor.AnyAnnotation annotation

But the syntax is correct and maven is proper executable using the command 
line.

How to tell eclipse about this syntax?

Comment: Did you install lombok into your Eclispe (by running `lombok.jar`)?

Comment: Using the combination of Lombok and Eclipse always causes the difficult question whether the problem is caused by Lombok inside of Eclipse or by the Eclipse JDT compiler. First check whether Lombok is installed into Eclipse correctly and see if that helps. Otherwise you could create a simple example that is using such an annotation but doesn't require lombok to see if this is a general problem with the Eclipse JDT Java compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot! This was the solution. I was looking for a plugin 
or something like this using the eclipse market place without 
success. To have a detailed look at the lombok site I don't had 
in my mind. See here: https://projectlombok.org/download.html